# Removing duplicates with filters and formulas in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have almost 96000 rows of data so I can't use the true false method with formulas or filters because excel takes too long to process then goes to not responding.

Does anyone know an alternate solution please?

Comment: You could try to work in chunks - replacing with values as each chunk is processed. You could speed this up more by disabling automatic calculation for each block also.

The best method would probably be a Macro to do this, but its not something you've mentioned.

Comment: Because i am not macro user, infect i do not know any thing about macro..
I am beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formula `"Unique"` for this problem if you are using spreadsheets, [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) is a link for your reference. If you are using excel follow this [tutorial](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/remove-duplicates.html).

Comment: This isn't a function in Excel - but only in Google sheets. I imagine it is just as memory hungry as the other solutions also.